# Равномерно разделить строки на подстроки

Tags: python, алгоритм, строки, классификация, данные

Есть список строк, состоящий из цифр. Как распределить эти строки на достаточно равномерные классы/кластеры? Класс -- это какая-то подстрока от начала строки. Чем "уже" класс, тем больше длина его подстроки.

Объясню на примере:

```
['123', '124', '125', '1', '2', '1256']
```

Тут строки с первой цифрой `1` встречаются часто, а с первой цифрой `2` - редко. Поэтому `2` будет отдельным классом, а `1` можно поделить на подклассы, чтобы распределение было более равномерным. Так что результат примерно такой (класс и его элементы):

```
{
'2': ['2'], 
'125': ['125', '1256'],
'12': ['123', '124'],  # 125 не включается, т.к. у него свой более узкий логически класс = более длинная построка
'1': ['1'] # аналогично тут нет 12 и 125
}
```

Задача в том, чтобы вот так вот распределить строки на классы, чтобы количество элементов в каждом классе не сильно отличалось. В примере либо 2, либо 1 элемент, т.е. разница 1, что очень хорошо для тысяч строк из моего датасета. Если бы мы разделили просто на 2 класса `1` и `2`, то разница была бы 5 против 1, т.е. 4, что уже хуже, чем 1.

Надо это для равномерного распределения данных для машинного обучения.

Приветствуются любые идеи, алгоритм или Python-код.

Comment: По-моему здесь имеет место ["Ошибка микроскопа-молотка" или "Ошибка XY"](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/) - попробуйте описать что обозначают значения в списке, какой алгоритм классификации вы хотите использовать и  что вы хотите получить в результате.

Comment: @MaxU хочу предсказывать класс в большой таксономии типа https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Биологическая_систематика, проблема в том, что в моих данных некоторые классы очень маленькие, некоторые очень большие, поэтому хочу сделать классы более-менее равномерными

Comment: Из идей можно поделить список на 1 и 2, получится не равномерный так что   проходим по 1 списку разбивая его на более мелкие. Потом по списку 2, и тд.